# How to convert white spaces string in to array

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting value like :this variable contains both English and Arabic value with some white space. But I want only English characters from that string but I am not able to get this I tried in both jquery and php

```
$country=India       هىيهش
```

Now I want to get only India from this how can I get this value.
Need a solution for jquery or php ..
I tried both split in jquery and explode in php but not working. Please help me related this.
I'm stuck here not getting any solution from there

situation :

html :

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="border: px solid pink;">
    <div class="col-md-3 no-padding label-set" >
            <label for="ex1" class="label-fsize">Country</label>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                <select class="form-control back-color classic16 geo_map" style="text-align: center !important;" id="countries" name="countries" placeholder="">
                    <option value=""  >Select&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;??????</option>
                        @foreach($result['countries'] as $countries)
                            <option value="{{$countries->id}}">{{$countries->country_eng}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$countries->country_arb}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <span class="text-danger text_error help-inline" id="countries_error">{{ $errors->first('lname_eng') }}</span>
               </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-padding label-set">
            <label for="ex1" style="float: right;" class="label-fsize">???????</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('blur', '.geo_map', function () {

            var countries = $('#countries').find(":selected").text();

})
})
```

Comment: You could `split` along whitespace, I guess?

Comment: do u have any idea ???

Comment: can u please update my question ??

Comment: @Sneha: If you want to update your question, just click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50894909/edit) word below your question.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in `PHP`:

```
$country = 'India       هىيهش';
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $country, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($words);
```

More information about `preg_split` in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Output will be:

```
(
    [0] => India
    [1] => هىيهش
)
```

DEMO [here](https://paiza.io/projects/8I24pPCk495Yv3nyw-heBw)

In `Javascript` it will be like this:

```js
var countries = "India       هىي";
console.log(countries.split(/\s+/).filter(t => t)[0]);
```

Comment: returning the error in console preg_split is not defined

Comment: It works for me, I have added a demo, please have a look

Comment: thanx its working but is there any other way in php ???? its working via js now thanx alot..

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain JavaScript problem. You can split the string by whitespaces, and the take the first element out, which should contain the English letters only:

```js
var string = "India       هىيهش";
console.log(string.split(/\s+/).shift());
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

You can use regex to capture the English letters.
I added 0-9 also in case that is needed.
I use preg_match_all, also just in case it's needed. If some word is placed after the Arabic then it will capture that too.

```
$country="India       هىيهش      Asia";

Preg_match_all("/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/", $country, $match);

Var_dump($match);
```

https://3v4l.org/NlUdO

Comment: @Sneha 3v4l is not lying. It does work. It's quite obvius the error is on your end as you have said nothing works here. It's you that do something wrong, the codes work.